# How do you push a docker database image with data?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I understand docker images for databases generally store the data on a volume. And this volume can be mounted.

I'm trying to make a docker container with some default data.

What happens if you don't specify a volume? Will the data just be stored on the docker-image? Does that have space issues? I'm wondering if I can just copy the default docker data directory to a docker image as part of building it.

Or what happens if you run mongo locally and create a local volume then mount the volume to the mongo container as part of the build? Is that even possible or can you only specify mounts when running a docker container? And if I deploy the mongo image to docker hub will it have the data stored in the volume?

Answer (score 0):

(written for anyone who happens across this)
Since the access requirements for code often differ from data and version control should illustrate development rather than, say, a backup of some database changes, the common recommendation is to keep the data separate from the source code. Docker tutorials focus on [local backup](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and fighting this paradigm may prove difficult.

**Yes**, it is possible to copy any data into the image during build. As long as the MongoDB configuration points to the directory into which the database files were copied, it will see the data on launch. **However**, any changes made to the database will be saved only in the running container and be lost when it is removed (unless you create *another* image from that container). Normally they would be saved to the data directory, but mounting a data volume on `run` replaces whatever the image had at that location.

[How to Back Up Your Data Volumes to Docker Hub](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-backup-your-data-volumes-to-docker-hub) offers a compromise that uncouples the data image from the application image. First, it extends the local backup process for creating a *data container* by then turning the container into an image and pushing it:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from data-container-backup --name tmp-backup -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /folderToBackup
docker run -d -v $(pwd):/backup --name data-backup ubuntu /bin/sh -c "cd / && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar
docker commit data-backup repo/data-backup:$VERSION
docker push repo/data-backup:$VERSION
```

You can then use --volumes-from to run another container that uses folders from the data container as a data volume.

```
docker run -v /folderToBackup --entrypoint "bin/sh" --name data-container repo/data-backup:${VERSION}
docker run --volumes-from=data-container repo/whatEver
```

(your image names, container names and paths will vary)